# how do i select all tags in my twig template in grav?

Tags: php, twig, grav

I have the following code in my `default.html.twig` file to display all the titles of the blog pages with the `tag` : `dog`:

```
<ul>
        {% for post in taxonomy.findTaxonomy({'tag':'dog'}) %}
        <li>{{ post.title }}<span>(0)</span></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

What i would really like to do is find all the tags and not just the `dog` tag, so i did the following:

```
<ul>
        {% for post in taxonomy.findTaxonomy({'tag':'all'}) %}
        <li>{{ post.title }}<span>(0)</span></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

I changed the `dog` to `all` , but this does't really give me any results. I checked the documentation here for `findTaxonomy` , but it does't help much , also in the `<span></span>` inside the `<li>` , I would like to show how many articles for this perticular tag have been posted , eg. if there are five articles for the tag `popcorn` the html spitedd out should be:

`<li>popcorn <span>(5)</span></li>`. How do i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

What about not using findTaxonomy and just iterate on all elements like this:

```
    {% for post in yourCollection %}
        <li>{{ post.title }}<span>(0)</span></li>
    {% endfor %}
```

Eventually using an "if" statement on post.tag in case you want to check something (defined value, not '', etc).

Comment: what would be yourCollection ?

Comment: The array you're iterating over in the for loop (otherwise this loop has no sense, or I miss something).
Let say itemList contains multiple items having a tag attribute.
I would do:
{% for item in itemList if item.tag is not null and item.tag is not empty %} (display what you want...)